# CSS Tables, Invert order of displayed content

Tags: html, css

I know this is a bit bleeding edge, but here's the question anyway:

Given

```
<div id="one">First Div</div>
<div id="two">Second Div</div>
```

...

```
#one, #two { display: table-cell; }
```

... which gives me a lovely side-by-side arrangement of the div's with #one on the left and #two on the right.

Is there anyway to put #two on the left and #one on the right, using `display: table-cell;`, and without changing the order of the divs in the HTML?

I ask, because I'd like to keep #one above #two in the HTML for SEO reasons, but I'd like #two to be to the right of #one for aesthetic reasons.  I know how to do this using floats/absolute positioning/margins/etc., but I was wondering if there was a way I can do it using the newer CSS table display properties (which I much prefer).

Any thoughts?

Comment: While new CSS features are nice, I would recommend you to use a cross-browser compatible solution. `float: right;` on first or both elements reverses the horizontal order of the elements while still allowing other elements to be affected by their position, width and height.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but for this site I can afford to aggressively target newer browsers and employ newer technology (HTML5 & CSS3). I know the existing methods for doing this; I was looking to understand the newer methods.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can (ab)use the text direction **warning, evil ahead**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">First Div</div>
    <div id="two">Second Div</div>
</div>

<style>
    #container { direction: rtl; }
    #one, #two { display: table-cell; direction: ltr;}
</style>
```

Comment: Clever solution =) Have you tested it in more browsers? You could run it through http://www.browsershots.org/

Comment: Interesting; didn't know about direction. However, this necessitates a wrapper element... 

Is this solution evil because it is an abuse of the property, or for another reason?

Comment: @neezer because it's an abuse of the direction property

Comment: you could also use float:right, which places #one first to the right, and #two second to the right.

Comment: @txwikinger he's trying to keep the display as table-cell - using float would force it to be block

Comment: This is nice! But any way to further floating cell #two to the left so that in RWD, cell #two will be at the top, cell #one will be at the bottom? E.g. `#two { float: left; }` ?

Comment: ...until this goes to localization. This will work on small sites but if you go international this will likely break your stuff.

Comment: 6 years later, this still works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="middle" style="background-color: blue;">
           <h4>Left Col placed middle</h4>
           <p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right" style="background-color: red;">          
           <h4>Middle Col placed right side</h4>
           <p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="left" style="background-color: yellow;">
           <h4>Right Col placed left side</h4>
           <p>...</p>
        </div>
   </div>

<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        display: flex;
    }
    .container > .left{
        order:1;
    }
    .container > .middle{           
        order:2;
    }
    .container > .right{
        order:3;
    }

    .left, .middle, .right {
        display:table-cell;         
    }
 </style>
```

I use flexbox. You can also change count of divs. For example put more divs with left class, then they will be placed left side even if they are declared after.

I tried @Greg example, but it doesn't work on IE.