# Hover element to effect sibling element

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar with a list of links and a search bar. It looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="link">Link 1</li>
  <li class="link">Link 2</li>
  <li class="link">Link 3</li>
  <li class="link search">search</li>
</ul>
```

When the user hovers the `"search"` element, I want to

Apply a width of 500px to the hovered search elements

Apply a margin of -150px to the sibling `"link"` element

The CSS that I've written to do this is:

```
  ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
}

.link {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.search {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
}

.search:hover{
  width: 500px
}

.search:hover + .link {
  margin-left: -150px;
}
```

This however has no effect on the sibling `"link"` elements

With pure CSS, is it possible to apply the the declarations `"margin-left: -150px"` on the hover of `"search"`?

I've created a fiddle here to illustrate the problem

https://jsfiddle.net/qut1nz9j/

Comment: There's no previous sibling selector in CSS yet.

Comment: CSS can't go "backwards"...

Comment: Ok... looks like i'll have to figure out another way to do this

Comment: You probably need JS to do something like that, since you want to target a previous DOM element.

Comment: @AdamScott I posted an answer for you. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: @LGSon just take a look - this is perfect, thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) you can do like this. [(Current browser support ~96%)`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

The trick is you put the search link first in your markup and use `order` to show it last. With this you can use the sibling selector `~` to achieve what you want.

```css
nav {
  width: 700px;
  background: green;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.link {
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 80px;
  order: 1;
}
.search {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  order: 2;
}
.search:hover {
  width: 500px
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>Site Name</span>

  <ul>
    <li class="link search">search</li>
    <li class="link">Link 1</li>
    <li class="link">Link 2</li>
    <li class="link">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

*Thanks to [Joum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24098/joum), here is a nice addition to my solution: [https://jsbin.com/yipujadewi/edit?css,output](https://jsbin.com/yipujadewi/edit?css,output_)*

---

If someone really need to target previous sibling and can't use `flex`, here is an abuse of `direction: ltr/rtl` in combination with `display: table`.

Src: [CSS Tables, Invert order of displayed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138639/css-tables-invert-order-of-displayed-content/1138673#1138673)

```css
nav {
  width: 700px;
  background: green;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-table;
  direction: rtl;
}
.link {
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 80px;
  display: table-cell;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
}
.search {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
}
.search:hover {
  width: 500px
}
.search:hover ~ .link {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>Site Name</span>

  <ul>
    <li class="link search">search</li>
    <li class="link">Link 3</li>
    <li class="link">Link 2</li>
    <li class="link">Link 1</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen your edit. Although I think you should warn OP about `flex`'s shortcomings... It's not available everywhere (unfortunately)...

Comment: @Joum It is available in all major browsers current version and 1-2 version back, approx. 96% of all users ... and I updated my answer as well

Comment: 96% of what users? mobile users? desktop users? refrigerator users? smartTV users? Look, I agree it's both a useful and elegant solution, just thought it would be useful to point it out. btw, took the liberty of doing this to your code in case it helps OP: https://jsbin.com/yipujadewi/edit?css,output

Comment: @Joum Follow link in my answer and you'll see the stats ... and wonderful addition .. my I add a link to it in my answer?